# How to add onError and onNull to $dateFromString in an aggregation update using MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I'm currently working on a project which use MongoTemplate and I would like to do this simply query:

```json
db.collection.update({
  timestamp: null
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      timestamp: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$myvalue",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          onError: "$$NOW",
          onNull: "$$NOW"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

But I'm stuck on the validation parts, I can't find the way to add `onError` and `onNull` into the query.

Currently my code is:

```java
AggregationUpdate update = AggregationUpdate.update()
                .set("timestamp").toValue(DateOperators.dateFromString("$myvalue")
                        .withFormat("%Y-%m-%d"));

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(
        new Query(Criteria.where("timestamp").is(null)),
        update,
        MyClass.class
);
```

And this works fine... but I'd like to control the errors using `onError` and `onNull`.

Is that possible using MongoTemplate?

`DateOperators.dateFromString()` has methods `withFormat()` and `withTimezone()` but I can't see `onError()` and `onNull()`, to match with all options according to [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encounter a similar issue recently so I put here the solution I came up with.

I ends up to construct *"$dateFromString"* by hand, so your would become :

```
AggregationUpdate update = AggregationUpdate.update()
  .set("timestamp").toValue(new BasicDBObject("$dateFromString", 
    new BasicDBObject("dateString", "$myvalue")
      .append("format", "%Y-%m-%d")
      .append("onError", "$$NOW")
      .append("onNull", "$$NOW")));
```